# How to recreate the QR scanning from your phone's camera app

Tags: android, qr-code, google-vision

I have a particular QR code I'm trying to create an app to read.

I've installed the [vision sample app from Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader), and it doesn't detect the QR code. When I use the QR scanner on my phone (by swiping down the notification drawer from the top), it also doesn't detect the QR code.

The ZXing library doesn't work either.

However, when I open the Camera app on my phone (Samsung S8), it detects the QR code just fine.

Why are these different, and how do I recreate what the camera is doing?

Comment: What kind of qr code type re you using?

Comment: @javdromero It's a qr code printed out on a piece of paper

Comment: "qr code printed out on a piece of paper". That's not very helpful information. Please provide an image of your QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this lib
https://github.com/jenly1314/ZXingLite

I think is the most used now

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. I switched to this from that.